# Parsing multidimensional JSON arrays, nested arrays

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following JSON that I want to parse, What I want to get is all the "name" and "count" when the key is "pubYear", or "docType". I can loop through summaries and get all the names and counts for both "pubYear", and "docType" but I can't get the individual ones. Any suggestion ? I'm using JQuery to parse this.

```
{
  "summaries": [
    {
      "name": "Publication Year",
      "pubYear": [
        { "name": "2001", "count": 9, "stars": "1 Star" },
        { "name": "2009", "count": 24, "stars": "4 Stars" },
        { "name": "2010", "count": 3, "stars": "2 Stars" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Document type",
      "docType": [
        { "name": "Book", "count": 20 },
        { "name": "Journal", "count": 2 }
      ]
    }
  ]      
}

$.getJSON("js/init.json", function(json) {
$.each(json.summaries, function(key, data) {
      $.each(data.docType, function(entryIndex, entry) {
      console.log(this.name);
      });
    });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the individual ones"?  Can you show the loop you currently have?

Comment: You probably want to check if `data` has `docType` or `pubYear` property before looping over it.  But, what's the issue you are having?  Where are you having trouble?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to test for "pubYear", if it exists, then I want to get all it's "name" values such as "2001"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this,

**HTML :**

```
<button class="pubYear" >pubYear</button>
<button class="docType" >docType</button>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
var json=JSON.parse('{  "summaries": [    {      "name": "Publication Year",      "pubYear": [        { "name": "2001", "count": 9, "stars": "1 Star" },        { "name": "2009", "count": 24, "stars": "4 Stars" },        { "name": "2010", "count": 3, "stars": "2 Stars" }      ]    },    {      "name": "Document type",      "docType": [        { "name": "Book", "count": 20 },        { "name": "Journal", "count": 2 }      ]    }  ]      }');
$('button.pubYear,button.docType').click(function(){
    var but=$(this).attr('class')
    var but1=but=="pubYear"?0:1;
    $.each(json.summaries[but1][but],function(){
        console.log(this.name+' : '+this.count);
    });
})
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gNGM5/1/)</kbd>

To get an individual value do ,

```
json.summaries[1].docType[0].name
json.summaries[1].docType[1].name
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/gNGM5/3/)</kbd>